# Только определенные значения в свойстве интерфейса

Tags: typescript

У меня есть интерфейс:

```js
export interface IAuthScreenProps {
  underInputText: string;
  buttonText: string;
  type: string ;
}
```

Как мне сделать, чтобы `type` мог принимать только определенные значения. Например, только `"register"` и `"auth"` вместо просто `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
export interface IAuthScreenProps {
  underInputText: string;
  buttonText: string;
  type: "register" | "auth";
}
```